# Как убрать внутренние отступы QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qtextbrowser

При создании `QTextBrowser` от границы до текста есть отступ.

Как возможно его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        text = "У меня есть внутренний отступ от границы элемента"
        textArea = QTextBrowser()
        textArea.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #000;")
        textArea.append(text)

        vbox.addWidget(textArea)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.resize(700,540)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin тут отступы именно внутри QTextBrowser, а не между QTextBrowser и границами Layout. Для этого border показателен в примере.

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю что это будет, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        text = "У меня уже нет внутренних отступов от границы элемента"
        textArea = QTextBrowser() 
#        textArea.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #000;") 
        textArea.append(text)
        textArea.append("Hello World !")
        textArea.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        vbox.addWidget(textArea)


QSS = """
QTextBrowser {
    background-color: #232629;  
    color: #0FF0F1;
}

QTextBrowser:hover,
QTextBrowser:!hover,
QTextBrowser::selected,
QTextBrowser::pressed {
    border: 4px solid #f0f0f0;    
    padding: -4px 0px 0px -4px;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w  = Demo()
    w.resize(700,540)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @WD_KMS что не так с моим ответом ? Ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: В таком варианте получается только визуально, что нет отступа. Стоит поставить слева элемент какой-нибудь, и будет понятно, что отступ всё-таки есть. Важно именно расположение текста относительно других элементов.

Comment: @WD_KMS вы не писали об этих деталях ранее. Добавьте это в вопрос и добавьте пример с элементом слева, а также изобразите что вы желаете получить.